# VSE: strobing Video frames AS WELL as the masking frames?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

I have a 60 fps (which I have to leave as is since changing it will mess up all the video and audio sync) video.
I have a video strip that I want to strobe down to 10 fps (so Strobe value under Strip property is 6.0).
The trouble is that I have a masking that make some sections more bright. I was able to create the 10fps for the video, but the masking animation is still 60 fps (so you see the video frames as 10 fps but you still see the masking animation moving about on top of the 10fps video)

How do I make the masking animation to 10 fps as well?

Help. Thanks.

Comment: would a solution involving ffmpeg work for you?

ei. I can imagine a solution where you import your video as two separate streams with relevant alpha channels and then you pixel-wise add your strobe'd video png stream to every 6th png in the main png stream?

Comment: @WhisperingShiba I am trying a solution that may be similar to what you're thinking:  use a color strip with the masking on it, and render it. Then import the ffmpeg, then use the strip as Mask in the Modifier of the main video.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution:
use a color strip with the masking on it, and render it. Then import the ffmpeg and hide it, then use the strip as Mask in the Modifier of the main video. Have the main video Strobe to 6.0. Then render the entire thing, and see the mask also strobe at 6 or close to it.